# как найти сумму элементов объектов,но только через петлю (цикл) for..../тоже самое только через петлю (цикл) for.?

Tags: javascript, классы, циклы, объекты, конструктор

```js
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  static distance(a, b) {
    const dx = a.x - b.x;
    const dy = a.y - b.y;
    return Math.hypot(dx, dy);
  }}
const p1 = new Point(5, 5);
const p2 = new Point(10, 10);
p1.distance;    
p2.distance;    
console.log(Point.distance(p1, p2));
```

Comment: Что такое "сумму элементов объектов"?

Comment: объект p1 х + р2 х (5+10) и объект p1 у+ р2 у (5+10) и это сделать через петлю for

Comment: Что "объект p1 х + р2 х"?

Comment: есть свойство х и у  у одного и другого объекта ,нужно найти общую сумму свойства х двох объектов и у двох объектов

Comment: О, что-то начинает проясняться! Двох объектов - это можно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  static distance(a, b) {
    const dx = a.x - b.x;
    const dy = a.y - b.y;
    return Math.hypot(dx, dy);
  }
  static add(a, b) {
    return Point.addAll(a, b);
  }
  static addAll() {
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      x += arguments[i].x;
      y += arguments[i].y;
    }
    return new Point(x, y);
  }
}
const p1 = new Point(5, 5);
const p2 = new Point(10, 10);
console.log(Point.distance(p1, p2));
console.log(Point.add(p1, p2));
console.log(Point.addAll(new Point(1, -1), new Point(2, -2), new Point(3, -3)));
```

Comment: но только обезательное условиям должно быть через петлю for сделать думал както так for (let i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
 return sum += this.x[i];